# Calculating in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calculator

I'm very new to Google spreadsheet and I've played around with functions but I'm not too sure how to create what I'm looking for.
I'm trying to make a calculator for a game where people can input their settings and based on their settings and the desired stats they want their hero to be by the end it will spit out results.

The problem I'm having is I'm not sure what formula you use. Here is the document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X5Mb24c8C4SblrsSBSoFuf8sB3fomM_X20isJO8KHLI/edit?usp=sharing

I was thinking IF D4 is 2★ and they want to get to +5 then it would follow I16's Rules.
Not sure if this makes a whole lot of sense. But basically Im trying to get

IF D4 = 2★ Then Results.
BUT if D4 = 3★ Then Different Results.
Not sure how to do this on one cell. If further explaination is needed let me know, The game is based off of 7knights if that helps at all.

Comment: What cell makes it go to row 16, not 15 or 14?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question so all the necessary info is in it? A link is great for reference, but that sheet is subject to change so it won't help future users much.

Answer (score 0):

Still a little bit confused on what your if statements are to contain, and what the dependent results should be - but from your last statement in the question it sounds like your just wanting a if statement to demonstrate the varying conditions?

ie:

```
=IF(D4="★★","RESULTS",IF(D4="★★★","OTHER RESULTS","OTHERWISE DEFAULT"))
```

I can easily modify this with real results/examples if you help me to understand what you actually want the end result to look like.